# How can this kind of table be done in latex?

Tags: tables

Help with multicolumn table in latex. Thanks.

[image]

This is what I have (so far):

```
\begin{document} 
\begin{table} 
\begin{tabular}{c|c} 
  \begin{tabular}{c|c} 
   a & b \\ \hline 
   c & d 
   \end{tabular} 
     & b \\ \hline 
   c & d 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Second try, far from perfect and very complicated:

```
\documentclass[aps,preprint,amsmath,floatfix]{revtex4}

\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\begin{tabular}{c|c}

\mbox{
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}

\mbox{
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        \mbox{\bm{$8\otimes 8$}} &
        \begin{tabular}{c}
            $\bm{27}$ \\
            2 \\
            1 \\
            1
        \end{tabular}\\
        \hline

        \mbox{
            \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
                1 & $\frac{1}{2}$ & $\frac{1}{2}$ &  & 1 & $\frac{1}{2}$ & $\frac{1}{2}$
            \end{tabular}
        }  & 1 \\
    \end{tabular}
} &
\begin{tabular}{c}
        $\bm{27}$ \\
        2 \\
        1 \\
        0
\end{tabular} &
\begin{tabular}{c}
$\bm{\bar{10}}$ \\
2 \\
0 \\
0
\end{tabular} \\
    \hline

\mbox{
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
        1 & $\frac{1}{2}$ & $\frac{1}{2}$ &  & 1 & $\frac{1}{2}$ & $-\frac{1}{2}$
    \end{tabular}
}  & $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$ & $-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$ \\
    \hline

    \mbox{
        \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
            1 & $\frac{1}{2}$ & $-\frac{1}{2}$ &  & 1 & $\frac{1}{2}$ & $\frac{1}{2}$
        \end{tabular}
    }  & $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$ & $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$ 
\end{tabular}
}

&
\mbox{
\begin{tabular}{c}
\bf{27} \\
2 \\
1 \\
$-1$
\end{tabular}
} \\

\hline

\mbox{
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccc}
1 & $\frac{1}{2}$ & $-\frac{1}{2}$ &  & 1 & $\frac{1}{2}$ & $-\frac{1}{2}$
    \end{tabular}
}

&
1

\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far? Where you suck? This site doesn't provide service "we-will-do-instead-of-you ...

Answer (score 8):

Do you mean something like this?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{picture}

\begin{document}

\begingroup\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\DIM}[1]{\dimexpr#1\unitlength-\@wholewidth\relax}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\block}[3]{\framebox(\DIM{#1},\DIM{#2}){#3}}
\newcommand{\HOR}[2]{\makebox[#1\unitlength][s]{#2}}
\newcommand{\VER}[2]{\vbox to #1\unitlength{#2}}
\newcommand{\VB}[1]{\hbox to\unitlength{\hss$#1$\hss}}
\begin{picture}(7,7)
\put(1.5,4.5){\makebox(0,0){$\underset{\sim}{8}\otimes\underset{\sim}{8}$}}
\put(0,3){%
  \block{3}{1}{\HOR{3}{%
    $\hfill1\hfill\frac{1}{2}\hfill\frac{1}{2}\hspace{\stretch{2}}%
     1\hfill\frac{1}{2}\hfill\frac{1}{2}\hfill$%
  }}%
}
\put(1,1){\block{3}{1}{%
  \block{3}{1}{\HOR{3}{%
    $\hfill1\hfill\frac{1}{2}\hfill{-}\frac{1}{2}\hspace{\stretch{2}}%
     1\hfill\frac{1}{2}\hfill\frac{1}{2}\hfill$%
  }}%
}}
\put(1,2){\block{3}{1}{%
  \block{3}{1}{\HOR{3}{%
    $\hfill1\hfill\frac{1}{2}\hfill\frac{1}{2}\hspace{\stretch{2}}%
     1\hfill\frac{1}{2}\hfill{-}\frac{1}{2}\hfill$%
  }}%
}}
\put(3,0){\block{3}{1}{%
  \block{3}{1}{\HOR{3}{%
    $\hfill1\hfill\frac{1}{2}\hfill{-}\frac{1}{2}\hspace{\stretch{2}}%
     1\hfill\frac{1}{2}\hfill{-}\frac{1}{2}\hfill$%
  }}%
}}
\put(3,3){\block{1}{1}{\HOR{1}{\hfill$1\vphantom{\frac{1}{2}}$\hfill}}}
\put(3,4){\block{1}{3}{%
  \VER{3}{%
    \vfill\VB{\underset{\sim}{27}}\vfill\VB{2}\vfill\VB{1}\vfill\VB{1}\vfill
  }%
}}
\put(4,1){\block{1}{1}{\HOR{1}{\hfill$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$\hfill}}}
\put(4,2){\block{1}{1}{\HOR{1}{\hfill$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$\hfill}}}
\put(4,3){\block{1}{3}{%
  \VER{3}{%
    \vfill\VB{\underset{\sim}{27}}\vfill\VB{2}\vfill\VB{1}\vfill\VB{0}\vfill
  }%
}}
\put(5,1){\block{1}{1}{\HOR{1}{\hfill$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$\hfill}}}
\put(5,2){\block{1}{1}{\HOR{1}{\hfill$-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$\hfill}}}
\put(5,3){\block{1}{3}{%
  \VER{3}{%
    \vfill\VB{\underset{\sim}{\overline{10}}}\vfill\VB{2}\vfill\VB{0}\vfill\VB{0}\vfill
  }%
}}
\put(6,0){\block{1}{1}{\HOR{1}{\hfill$1\vphantom{\frac{1}{2}}$\hfill}}}
\put(6,1){\block{1}{3}{%
  \VER{3}{%
    \vfill\VB{\underset{\sim}{27}}\vfill\VB{2}\vfill\VB{1}\vfill\VB{-1}\vfill
  }%
}}
\end{picture}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Gabo Sorry: there's a lot of *ad hoc* code. Maybe this can be done with a standard table, but I felt that direct manipulation and positioning would be faster.

Comment: instead of `picture` environment,  using `tikzpicture` is easier to read

Comment: @BlackMild Sure! Go forward and I'll be glad to upvote.

Answer (score 3):

You may also typeset your figure using [cals](https://ctan.org/pkg/cals), but even if a `calstable` is simpler than `tabular` and friends to twist to produce a pretty decent copy, it it obvious that @egreg's solution is better and much simpler.

**NB**! *In the previous message, I unfortunately forgot to mention that I copied the code regarding the content of the cells from @egreg's example.*

In this second version, I have simplified the code. I have reduced the number of column to seven, with the cell in row four 50 per cent wider than the other column. I have also optimised the spacing some places.

To have an exact copy or your original tabular, you need to tweak alignments in my code ‘by hand’.

Here is what I received and the code:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, cals}

\let\nc=\nullcell                                                  % Shortcuts
\let\sc=\spancontent

\begin{document}

\begin{calstable}[c]
% Defining 14 equal columns
\colwidths{{1.95cm}{1.3cm}{1.3cm}{1.3cm}{1.3cm}{1.3cm}{1.3cm}
            }

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{0.3pt}   % Outside frame rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.03pt}
\def\cals@bodyrs@width{0.3pt}
\cals@setpadding{Ag}
\cals@setcellprevdepth{Al}
\def\cals@cs@width{0.3pt}             % Inside rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@rs@width{0.3pt}
\def\cals@bgcolor{}

\def\bb{\ifx\cals@borderB\relax     % Bottom Border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderB{0.0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderB\relax\fi}

\def\rb{\ifx\cals@borderR\relax     % Right Border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderR{0.0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderR\relax\fi}

\def\lb{\ifx\cals@borderL\relax     % Left Border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderL{0.0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderL\relax\fi}

\def\tb{\ifx\cals@borderT\relax     % Top Border switch (off-on)
    \def\cals@borderT{0.0pt}
\else \let\cals@borderT\relax\fi}

\def\cals@AtBeginCell{\vfil}
%\def\cals@AtEndCell{}

%% Start of tabular body, no header row
% R1B1
\brow
    \lb\tb\nc{lt}
    \nc{lt}
    \nc{rt}\tb\lb
    \nc{lrt}
    \tb\rb\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\rb\tb
    \ht\cals@current@row=1.3cm
\erow
%R2B2
\brow
    \lb\nc{l}
    \nc{}
    \nc{r}\lb
    \nc{lr}
    \nc{lrt}
    \nc{lrt}
    \rb\tb\cell{}\rb\tb
    \ht\cals@current@row=1.3cm
\erow
%R3B3
\brow
    \lb\nc{lb}
    \nc{b}
    \nc{rb}\alignC\sc{\vfill $\underset{\sim}{8}\otimes\underset{\sim}{8}$\\}\lb
    \nc{lrb}\alignC\sc{$\underset{\sim}{27}$\\\vfil $2$\\\vfil $1$\\\vfil $0$\vfil}
    \nc{lr}
    \nc{lr}
    \rb\tb\cell{}\rb\tb
    \ht\cals@current@row=1.3cm
\erow
%R4B4
\brow
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignL\sc{\hfill $1 \hfill\frac{1}{2}\hfill\frac{1}{2}\quad \hfill 1 \hfill\frac{1}{2} \hfill\frac{1}{2}$}
    \alignC\cell{$1$}
    \nc{lrb}\alignC\sc{$\underset{\sim}{27}$\\\vfil $2$\\\vfil $0$\\\vfil $0$\vspace{6.5pt}}
    \nc{lrb}\alignC\sc{$\underset{\sim}{\overline{10}}$\\\vfil $2$\\\vfil $0$\\\vfil $0$\vspace{6.5pt}}
    \nc{lrt}
    \ht\cals@current@row=1.3cm
\erow
%R5B5
\brow
    \lb\bb\cell{}\lb\bb
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignL\sc{\hfill $1 \hfill\frac{1}{2}\hfill\frac{1}{2}\quad \hfill 1 \hfill\frac{1}{2} \hfill-\frac{1}{2}$}
    \alignC\cell{$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$}
    \alignC\cell{$-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$}
    \nc{lr}
    \ht\cals@current@row=1.3cm
\erow
%R6B6
\brow
    \lb\bb\cell{}\lb\bb
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignL\sc{\hfill $1 \hfill-\frac{1}{2}\hfill\frac{1}{2}\quad \hfill 1 \hfill\frac{1}{2} \hfill\frac{1}{2}$}
    \alignC\cell{$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$}
    \alignC\cell{$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$}
    \nc{lrb}\alignC\sc{$\underset{\sim}{27}$\\\vfil $2$\\\vfil $0$\\\vfil $-0$\vspace{6.5pt}}
    \ht\cals@current@row=1.3cm
\erow
%R7B7
\brow
    \lb\bb\cell{}
    \cell{}
    \cell{}\lb\bb
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignL\sc{\hfill $1 \hfill\frac{1}{2}\hfill-\frac{1}{2}\quad \hfill 1 \hfill\frac{1}{2} \hfill-\frac{1}{2}$}
    \alignC\cell{$1$}
    \ht\cals@current@row=1.3cm
\erow
\makeatletter
\end{calstable}\par
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was done with `tikzpicture` using `tabular`, as in the original MWE, to create rows and columns. The *rows* use an adjustable `p{}` column to assure spacing. The *columns* use `arraystretch` to distribute the rows. Since the original MWE used bold rather than an `underset sim`, this does the same.

---

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[transform canvas={scale=0.7,xshift=0mm,yshift=-130mm},remember picture]
  \huge
%  \draw[step=1cm,yellow,very thin] (0,0) grid (14,13);
  \draw (6,0) rectangle node { \begin{tabular}{cccp{0.10cm}ccc}
    1 & $\frac{1}{2}$ & $-\frac{1}{2}$ & & 1 & $\frac{1}{2}$ & $-\frac{1}{2}$\\ \end{tabular}
  } (12,2);
  \draw (12,0) rectangle node {1} (14,2);
  \draw (2,2) rectangle node { \begin{tabular}{cccp{0.20cm}ccc}
    1 & $\frac{1}{2}$ & $-\frac{1}{2}$ & & 1 & $\frac{1}{2}$ & $\frac{1}{2}$\\ \end{tabular}
  } (8,4);
  \draw (8,2) rectangle node {$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$} (10,4);
  \draw (10,2) rectangle node {$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$} (12,4);
  \draw (12,2) rectangle node { \def\arraystretch{1.4} \begin{tabular}{c}
    ${\textbf{27}}$ \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ -1\\
    \end{tabular}
  } (14,8);
  \draw (2,4) rectangle node { \begin{tabular}{cccp{0.20cm}ccc}
    $1$ & $\frac{1}{2}$ & $\frac{1}{2}$ & & $1$ & $\frac{1}{2}$ & $-\frac{1}{2}$\\ \end{tabular}
  } (8,6);
  \draw (8,4) rectangle node {$\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$} (10,6);
  \draw (10,4) rectangle node {$-\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$} (12,6);
  \draw (0,6) rectangle node { \begin{tabular}{cccp{0.3cm}ccc}
    1 & $\frac{1}{2}$ & $\frac{1}{2}$ & & 1 & $\frac{1}{2}$ & $\frac{1}{2}$\\ \end{tabular}
  } (6,8);
  \draw (6,6) rectangle node {1} (8,8);
  \draw (6,8) rectangle node { \def\arraystretch{1.30} \begin{tabular}{c}
    ${\textbf{27}}$ \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ 1\\
    \end{tabular}
  } (8,13);
  \draw (8,6) rectangle node { \def\arraystretch{1.30} \begin{tabular}{c}
    ${\textbf{27}}$ \\ 2 \\ 1 \\ 0\\
    \end{tabular}
  } (10,11);
  \draw (10,6) rectangle node { \def\arraystretch{1.30} \begin{tabular}{c}
    ${\overline{\textbf{10}}}$ \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ 0\\
    \end{tabular}
  } (12,11);
  \draw (3,9) node {${\textbf{8}} \otimes {\textbf{8}}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

[image: Oddly shaped table]